# Given $\mathbb{V}(X)=25$ and $\mathbb{P}(X>20)>\frac{1}{4}$, find bounds of $\mathbb{E}(X)$.

Tags: probability

Let $X$ be a random variable with $\mathbb{V}(X)=25$

It also satisfies $\mathbb{P}(X>20)>\frac{1}{4}$.

Which of the following is true?

- $\mathbb{E}(X)>10$.
- $5<\mathbb{E}(X)\leq 10$.
- $0<\mathbb{E}(X)\leq 5$.
- $\mathbb{E}(X)\leq 0$.

I tried using Chebyshev's inequality and found out that $\mathbb{E}(X)>5$ but wasn't sure how to go on about it.

Comment: How did you use Chebyshev's inequality? You can solve the problem with a single use of Chebyshev's, but without seeing your work, I cannot tell where your work is deficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a fairly major hint, you should use Chebyshev's inequality to show
$$\mathbb{E}X \geq c - \sqrt{\frac{\mathbb{V}X}{\mathbb{P}(X\geq c)}}$$ (provided $\mathbb{P}(X\geq c) \neq 0$)

Answer (score -1):

There cannot be an upper limit on $E(X)$ - for example there is nothing to stop the distribution being centred around 100 or 1000. So option A is the only possibility.

We can check option A by trying to make E(X) as small as possible. Put $p(X=20)=0.25$ and $p(X=a)=0.75$. Then
$$E(X)=0.25*20+0.75*a=5+0.75a$$
$$E(X^2)=0.25*20^2+0.75*a^2=100+0.75a^2$$
$$Var(X)=100+0.75a^2-(5+0.75a)^2=25$$
which gives $a \approx 8.45$ and $E(X)\approx 11.3$. So option A is satisfied.

Comment: Thank @Brian. Now corrected.